# How do I avoid AWS API Gateway returning a 400 error?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have a use case for a simple redirector, and want to use API Gateway.

You can see that this link produces a 302 redirect taking you to some configurable page:

https://data.picnic-media.com/rubies?key=value

But this one has invalid characters and so returns a 400 error:

https://data.picnic-media.com/rubies?key={value}

I can't guarantee that all callers will always avoid using bad characters, so want the second case to do the redirect anyway. Is there anything I can do to fix this? It seems that the 400 error is returned even before it hits the things I can configure...

Comment: "redirect anyway" *...to where?* If the request is invalid, how do you determine the destination?

Comment: The redirect could be to any website that I define on the server-side...Thanks!

Comment: I don't see a solution, though it seems like API Gateway is being unnecessarily pedantic if they are considering `{` or `}` to be invalid in the query string.

Comment: mmm, yes, I've been coming to pretty much the same conclusion. Thanks for taking a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. As of now, the request fails before it reaches you API Gateway configuration. I do not have a work around for this.

Thanks for reporting. We will consider fixing this.

Comment: Thanks Balaji. Appreciate you looking into it. I think a fix for this would be really great given that API Gateway looks to be an expanding platform (with serverless framework etc)